# Primefaces datatable combine data in only one row

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using tomcat8 and primefaces 5.1 and I have the following code:

```
<p:dataTable var="price" value="#{HOTEL.hotel}">

<p:column headerText="Тип стая">
<h:outputText value="Единична" />
<h:outputText value="Двойна" />
<h:outputText value="Апартамент" />
<h:outputText value="Студио" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Брой">
<h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.room_1}" />
<h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.room_2}" />
<h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.apartment}" />
<h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.studio}" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Цена">
<h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.room_1_price}" />
<h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.room_2_price}" />
<h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.apartment_price}" />
<h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.studio_price}" />
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

When using the code above I get only table with one row and all data in one row not different row for each outputText as I thought it would be. I want 4 rows and the approprate data in them. I want the first column to be as it is with the hardocoded values and then for each of them the corresponding values from the DB.

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a pause on your current project and take time to go through a sane JSF book/tutorial in order to properly grasp the essential basic concepts.

Comment: Yes, I know but I have a deadline because it is a project for the university. I always pass jours on the net reading before posting a question here. I really appreciate the help from guys like you. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `dataTable` component in a wrong way. It just displays data in a tabular view and the only thing you're supposed to do, is to supply it with a `Collection` of model objects and explicitly *tell* which property from a model instance should be displayed under a certain column.

Also, I believe you have some issues in your model, i.e. the type of room ("Single", "Double", etc.) should be part of the room definition, but not hard-coded in a `dataTable` column. Same goes for the price of a room. Also, a `hotel` should consist of a `Collection` of rooms.

So, you can introduce a class, called `Room` which will hold the properties of a room in the hotel.

```
enum RoomType {
    SINGLE, DOUBLE, APPARTMENT, STUDIO;
}

class Room {
    private RoomType type;

    private Double price;

    //constructors, accessors, etc.
}
```

Then, in the `hotel` bean, you should have a `Collection` of `Room` objects, each of which will provide the info about the price and the type of the room. Also, it would be a `hotel`'s responsibility to provide the availability for a given type of room, which is why it should expose some more methods. Something like:

```
public class Hotel {
    private List<Room> rooms;

    public Integer checkAvailabilityFor(RoomType type) {
        //for example
        switch (type) {
            case SINGLE: { return 5; }
            case DOUBLE: { return 2; }
            case APPARTMENT : { return 1; }
            case STUDIO: { return 3; }
        }
    }

    //accessor(s) for the rooms list
}
```

Finally, in the `dataTable` component, you'd have something like:

```
<p:dataTable var="room" value="#{HOTEL.hotel.rooms}">

    <p:column headerText="Type">
        <p:outputText value="#{room.type}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Rooms available">
        <p:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.checkAvailabilityFor(room.type)}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Price">
        <p:column value="#{room.price}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```